# Iterating through a JSON file

Tags: json, vb.net

I am a newbie to handling JSON files and could do with some help.
I have some code below (GlobalQuote section) that pulls symbol/price/volume from AlphaVantage. This code works fine but the JSON file returned only has one record.

If I try process a different AlphaVantage function (BestMatches section) that returns multiple rows the code falls over. I get the following error:

> ERROR Bestmatches' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g.
> {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly. To fix this error either
> change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the
> deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection
> interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be
> deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added
> to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.

And if that can be fixed I guess iterating through the result should be a While/End while or similar.

Any help appreciated.

```json
{
    "Global Quote": {
        "01. symbol": "MSFT",
        "02. open": "259.3900",
        "03. high": "260.0900",
        "04. low": "256.0000",
        "05. price": "258.0600",
        "06. volume": "30000055",
        "07. latest trading day": "2023-02-17",
        "08. previous close": "262.1500",
        "09. change": "-4.0900",
        "10. change percent": "-1.5602%"
    }
}
```

Working code:

```
Public Class GlobalQuote_JSONResponse
        <Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("Global Quote")>
        Public Property GlobalQuote As GlobalQuote
  End Class

Public Class GlobalQuote
        <Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("01. symbol")>
        Public Property Symbol As String

        <Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("05. price")>
        Public Property Price As String

        <Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("06. volume")>
        Public Property Volume As String
    End Class


Private Async Sub Sample()
        Dim url = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=GLOBAL_QUOTE&symbol=MSFT&apikey=demo"
        Dim jsonData = Await client.GetStringAsync(url)
        Dim results = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of GlobalQuote_JSONResponse)(jsonData)

        Dim symbol As String = results.GlobalQuote.Symbol
        Dim Price As String = results.GlobalQuote.Price
        Dim Volume As String = results.GlobalQuote.Volume

        MsgBox(symbol & " " & Price & " " & Volume)

    End Sub
```

NOT Working code:

```json
{
    "bestMatches": [
        {
            "1. symbol": "TSCO.LON",
            "2. name": "Tesco PLC",
            "3. type": "Equity",
            "4. region": "United Kingdom",
            "5. marketOpen": "08:00",
            "6. marketClose": "16:30",
            "7. timezone": "UTC+01",
            "8. currency": "GBX",
            "9. matchScore": "0.7273"
        },
        {
            "1. symbol": "TSCDF",
            "2. name": "Tesco plc",
            "3. type": "Equity",
            "4. region": "United States",
            "5. marketOpen": "09:30",
            "6. marketClose": "16:00",
            "7. timezone": "UTC-04",
            "8. currency": "USD",
            "9. matchScore": "0.7143"
        },
        {
            "1. symbol": "TSCDY",
            "2. name": "Tesco plc",
            "3. type": "Equity",
            "4. region": "United States",
            "5. marketOpen": "09:30",
            "6. marketClose": "16:00",
            "7. timezone": "UTC-04",
            "8. currency": "USD",
            "9. matchScore": "0.7143"
        },
        {
            "1. symbol": "TCO2.FRK",
            "2. name": "TESCO PLC ADR/1 LS-05",
            "3. type": "Equity",
            "4. region": "Frankfurt",
            "5. marketOpen": "08:00",
            "6. marketClose": "20:00",
            "7. timezone": "UTC+02",
            "8. currency": "EUR",
            "9. matchScore": "0.5455"
        },
        {
            "1. symbol": "TCO0.FRK",
            "2. name": "TESCO PLC LS-0633333",
            "3. type": "Equity",
            "4. region": "Frankfurt",
            "5. marketOpen": "08:00",
            "6. marketClose": "20:00",
            "7. timezone": "UTC+02",
            "8. currency": "EUR",
            "9. matchScore": "0.5455"
        }
    ]
}
```

```
Public Class BestMatches_JSONResponse
        <Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("bestMatches")>
        Public Property BestMatches() As Bestmatches
End Class

Public Class Bestmatches
        <Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("2. name")>
        Public Property Name As String

        <Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("4. region")>
        Public Property Region As String
End Class


Private Async Sub StockSearch()
        Dim url = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=SYMBOL_SEARCH&keywords=tesco&apikey=demo"
        Dim jsonData = Await client.GetStringAsync(url)
        Dim results = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of BestMatches_JSONResponse)(jsonData)

        Dim name As String = results.BestMatches.Name
        Dim Region As String = results.BestMatches.Region

        MsgBox(name & " " & Region)

End Sub
```

Comment: "NOT Working code" And what is the problem? you need to tell us what is the error. We can not guess

Answer (score 0):

The primary difference between the working and non-working code is that the working json has only one occurrence of GlobalQuote. As pointed out by Jimi, the non-working json has multiple instances of bestMatches. The "[" following bestMatches indicates that it is an array. There is also an ending "]" at the end of the last occurrence. (Note if the brackets exist then you must use an array, even if there is only one occurrence.)

So you need to replace:

```
Public Class BestMatches_JSONResponse
    <Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("bestMatches")>
    Public Property BestMatches() As Bestmatches
End Class
```

With

```
Public Class BestMatches_JSONResponse
    <Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("bestMatches")>
    Public Property BestMatches As List(Of Bestmatches)
End Class
```

You will also need to subscript your output variables.

Replace

```
    Dim name As String = results.BestMatches.Name
    Dim Region As String = results.BestMatches.Region
```

With:

```
    Dim name As New List(Of String)
    Dim region As New List(Of String)

    For i = 0 To results.BestMatches.Count - 1
        name.Add(results.BestMatches(i).name)
        region.Add(results.BestMatches(i).Region)
    Next
```

FYI. There are a number of free websites that will accept a json string and generate the Class descriptions. This can save you a lot of time. (However, you will still need to understand Json syntax in order to process the data)

Comment: Thank you all very much. That is exactly the info I needed.